# Is there a way to handle comma separated data in a particular column in Abinitio

Tags: ab-initio

I do have a source team data sent as below:

| Name | ID | StateCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abc | 1 | CA,GE |
| Xyz | 2 | IL,MA |

As you can see the `StateCode` column has again comma separated values. Can anyone suggest how can the above records read in Ab Initio?

`Name` and `ID` are fixed length.

Comment: 1) what format you want to have in output? 2) you have to build "graph" (MP) and convert/proceed State Codes to format you need

Answer (score 1):

I've handled this in the past making a character that is not part of the data as the delimiter. The one I have used frequently is '\x01'. Another way is to use quotes around the data field. You can use read csv component to specify that option. Let me know if you have more questions. If you're looking to read a column with multiple values separated by commas, you could read them into a vector.